# How to link lpaho-mqtt3c for the given compiler command

Tags: compilation, mqtt, paho

I have build the paho mqtt c and c++ with the following commands,

```
$ git clone https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c.git
$ cd paho.mqtt.c
$ git checkout v1.3.1

$ cmake -Bbuild -H. -DPAHO_WITH_SSL=ON -DPAHO_ENABLE_TESTING=OFF
$ sudo cmake --build build/ --target install
$ sudo ldconfig

$ git clone https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp
$ cd paho.mqtt.cpp
$ cmake -Bbuild -H. -DPAHO_BUILD_DOCUMENTATION=TRUE -DPAHO_BUILD_SAMPLES=TRUE
$ sudo cmake --build build/ --target install
$ sudo ldconfig
```

Now, When I include the paho headers to establish client connection in my target file, it says undefined reference to 'MQTTCLient_create'

```
 g++ \
-m64 -Wno-write-strings \
-Iinclude \
speedway_embedded_example.cpp -lpaho-mqtt3c\
-Llib -lltkcpp_x86_64 -lltkcppimpinj_x86_64 -lxml2_x86_64 \
-L/usr/bin -ldl -lssl -lcrypto \
-o bin/speedwayr_x86_64
```

I have included the paho headers in my application as,

```
extern "C"{
#include <MQTTClient.h>
#include <MQTTClientPersistence.h>
}
```

Can anyone please help me to overcome this issue?

Comment: I've mentioned this before, please read the `g++` doc to understand what the different options are doing. Specifically the `-l` and `-L` options.

Comment: Then you will need to build the Paho library with the x86 compiler first. Then add the required `-L` and `-l` options to link it.

Comment: @hardillb, i have used -L option to link the paho-mqttpp3 please let me know, how to overcome this? I have paho-mqttpp3 in /usr/local/lib path also. I have tried with both the option.

Comment: @hardillb, somehow it's taking extra slash in front of /usr/local/libpaho-mqttpp3.so. How to overcome this?

Comment: The slash is not important, what is more likely is that you've built a 64bit version of the library (run `file /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqttpp3.so`)

Comment: @hardillb, after changing it as /usr/local/lib/lipaho-mqttpp3.so, still it points to undefined reference.

Comment: 1) `-L` points to a path not an individual library 2) isn't `MQTTClient_create` part of the C library not the C++ one?

Comment: Thank you, Got it. I should have linked it to -lpaho-mqtt3c instead of -lphao-mqttpp3. Now I changed  -L to point to a path

Comment: @hardillb, incompatibility is due to 64 bit, so does it mean to install 32 bit paho libraries, because I have tried with -m32 -lpaho-mqtt3c and this too doesnt work

Comment: @hardillb, thank you for explaining things patiently. Finally, I have change the command like in the post and its working fine. Thank You for taking me to right direction.

Comment: @hardillb, all the required libraries of the target application has been changed to 64 bit architecture.